# How to change color after clicking a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, bind

I have loop as below:

```js
data: {
  show: false
}
```

```css
.test {
  hight: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.test2 {
  hight: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div v-for="value in data" :key="value.id">
  <div class="test" v-bind:class="{ test2: show }" v-on:click="show = !show">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if I click any `div`, it will be changed all the divs's height from 15 to 10 or 10 to 15.

However, I want to change the only the `div` that I clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `show` variable for each element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   show: [],
    items: []
  },
  created() {
    fakeFetch().then((items) => {
       this.items = items;
       this.show = this.items.map(() => false);
    });
  },
  methods: {
   isShown(i) {
     return this.show[i]
    },
    changeShow(i) {
     Vue.set(this.show, i, !this.show[i]);
    }
  }
})

function fakeFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     let count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
     let result = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       result.push({ text: Math.random() });
     }
     resolve(result);
  })
}
```

```css
.test {
  height:10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.test2 {
  height: 35px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Items:</h2>
  <div 
  class="test" 
  :class="{ test2: isShown(index) }"
  @click="changeShow(index)" 
  v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** To avoid this routine with `show` array you can define each element as component and switch visibility inside it with single variable `show` .

Comment: Tks. The problem is that i must fetch data in mounted, so i can't write items like that

Comment: @hayumikuran you can prepare `show` array in `mounted` hook after data fetching as well.

Comment: And can you explain the this.items.map(() => false) for me?
What is the (), and can i repalce that into other value (like 'a', 'b'.....)

Comment: no i can't, because i don't know the how many value that the items  have or something like that

Comment: @hayumikuran this line just creates array with same length as items. I updated example in answer with fake fetching items.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set active variable, and bind class if it's equal to current button index

```
<div v-for="(value, index) in data" :key="index">
  <div class="some-class" :class="{'active-class': index === active}" @click="active=index"></div>
</div>

.....

 data: function () { 
  return { 
    active: undefined
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using only one variable to control the class of every item, to enable more specific changes, you should have a variable for each item.

If you are in control of the data you are displaying, you can declare it in a way like this

```
data: {
  items: [{id: 1, visible: false},
          {id: 2, visible: false},
          {id: 3, visible: false}]
}
```

and change the visible attribute instead of a global `show` variable.

If you are not, you may want to consider building it through a computed property

You can check this solution on this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejmdPX?editors=1111

Comment: Tks. The problem is that i must fetch data in mounted, so i can't write items like that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method to set the class you want.

If you run  `v-on:click="myFunc()"` you get an event that you can use to make changes to the specific element.

```
methods: {
  myFunc (event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("test2")
  }
}
```